# preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2 to be a valid callback in

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

```
$ent_check = empty($modSettings['disableEntityCheck']) ? 
    array('preg_replace_callback(\'~(&#(\d{1,7}|x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,6});)~e\', \'$func[\\\'entity_fix\\\'](\\\'\\2\\\')\', ', ')') : 
    array('', '');
```

> `Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '$func['entity_fix']('\2')', to be a valid callback in...`

I'm not quite sure what to do here. Any help from someone smarter than I would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The First issue here is Intent. Well, the 2nd Argument passed to `preg_replace_callback($arg1, $arg2...)` is expected to be a **Callable**. That is why you have that error. It is unclear where you are going with your code but perhaps the code below could throw more light and help you either rethink/clarify your question, intent + goal or revisit your code. Consider this:

```
<?php
    $string         = "&#2510 whatever &#5870 again whatever &#7885";
    $modSettings    = array('disableEntityCheck'=>array());
    $func           = array(
        "fix_stuff"     => function($param=20){ echo $param;},
        "do_stuff"      => function($param=10){ echo $param;},
        "entity_fix"    => function($matches ){ return $matches[0] . "YES!!! ";},
    );

    $ent_check  = empty($modSettings['disableEntityCheck']) ? array(preg_replace_callback('#\d#', $func['entity_fix'], $string )) :  array('', '');
    var_dump($ent_check);

    // DISPLAYS  
    array (size=1)
        0 => string '&#2YES!!! 5YES!!! 1YES!!! 0YES!!!  whatever &#5YES!!! 8YES!!! 7YES!!! 0YES!!!  again whatever &#7YES!!! 8YES!!! 8YES!!! 5YES!!! '
```

Notice that in the code above,  the 2nd Argument passed to `preg_replace_callback` is a function ***though passed as a*** **REFERENCE** ***to the 'entity_fix' Key of the array: $func***. This was intended to highlight the fact that it is also possible to pass the 2nd Argument in such a manner. It is hoped that this here gives you a little tip to kick off ;-)

Good Luck!!!